# Program for all languages

Tags: .net

I want to write a collection of methods that can be used by all languages.  Java, .net, php, javascript etc.

I've thought of using wcf or web services... what are my other options?

Comment: What do you mean by "all languages"? Does "all" include "all existing languages ever"? Does it include "all future languages that may be ever developed and that we haven't even dreamt about"?

Comment: Furthermore, the very concept of "method" does not exist in every language. It is an OO concept. Although mappings to other concepts could be made, it may make no sense at all to "use a method" from languages that lack similar enough constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to a web service solution since this will make the collection available to all languages that can program against these services which includes both client side scripts such as Javascript, server side such as php and normal desktop application languages.

Consuming SOAP services is easy and widely accessible.

You could consider a basic http implementation, but it will be a lot labour work just to achieve the same thing as a SOAP service. However, some languages might not be able to consume SOAP services but will be able to do a http request.

Comment: Yes, REST is arguably more consumable than SOAP, but there's SOAP support in most major languages.

Answer (score 0):

If your programming the methods in .net then use WCF.